# Get a pair key+value from a Map with a parameter passed in a method

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to get the key+value (one and only one pair for each iteration of the system) from a Map and I have writed this method:

```
public String findValueInMapForExcel(String paramToFind,   Map<String, String> myMap) {
    
    System.out.println("MAP: "+myMap); //Data inside are correct
    System.out.println("KEYSET: "+myMap.keySet()); //Data inside are correct

    //Get key+value without cycle

    return somethingForNow;
}
```

I need to get the key+value record for paramToFind possibly without cycle and I have choosen this way because this is part of an Excel file creation that usually has 60/80K rows and I think that it's better to create a Map one time and get the pair for each iteration rather than execute a ***for*** cycle for every row.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why the Java EE tag?

Comment: Is `paramToFind` the key?

Comment: What does “without cycle” mean?

Comment: @BasilBourque the entire project is based on JavaEE, Spring, Maven etc

Comment: But how does *your question* have anything to do with Java EE? If nothing, then delete tag.

Comment: @iota yes, I pass paramToFind, for example "foo" and I would get from my map the pair foo = 5 for example

Answer (score 4):

## Ask map for value belonging to your key

You seem to be working too hard. No need to write a method, just call [`Map#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)). No need to call `keySet`.

Example code.

```
Map< String , String > colorPlan = Map.of(
    "wall" , "Antique White" ,
    "trim" , "Arctic White" ,
    "accent" , "Flannel Grey" 
) ;
```

When you have a key in hand, ask the map for the matching value.

```
String key = "wall" ; 
String value = colorPlan.get( key ) ;  // Returns "Antique White".
```

At this point, we have both a key and a value in hand: "wall" and "Antique White".

We can make a string of them.

```
String output = key + "=" + value ;
```

> wall = Antique White

### `Map.Entry`

If want to deliver those two key and value objects as a pair, we can make a [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object by calling [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) method (notice uppercase versus lowercase).

```
Map.Entry < String , String > entry = Map.entry( key , value ) ;
```

### `record`

In Java 16 and later, you might prefer a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record ColorPlanItem ( String surface , String color ) {}
```

Usage.

```
ColorPlanItem item = new ColorPlanItem( key , value ) ;
…
String surface = item.surface() ; 
String color = item.color() ;
```

We could combine calls.

```
ColorPlanItem item = new ColorPlanItem( key , map.get( key ) ) ;
```

Add a check for element missing from the map.

```
ColorPlanItem item = new ColorPlanItem( key , Objects.requireNonNull( map.get( key ) ) ) ;
```

Comment: You missed the requirement from the question, *I need to get the key+value* and then from the comment, *I pass paramToFind, for example "foo" and I would get from my map the pair foo = 5*

Comment: Thx for your help, I don't know why but after a code modification (I have had 5 = foo now I have foo=5) the code work... before I obtain a null pointer exception

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Well in that case you could just return the `colorForWalls` and whatever your key is no? I assume the key is the input to the function anyways

Comment: @BennoGrimm - `colorForWalls` gives just value. You need to return `Map.Entry<String, String>`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I thought it obvious that we end with both the key and the value in hand. But very well, I added section on `Map.Entry` per your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `Map#get` to get the value for the key.

```
public Map.Entry<String, String> getEntry(String paramToFind,  Map<String, String> myMap) {
    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(paramToFind, myMap.get(paramToFind));
}
```

With Java 9+:

```
public Map.Entry<String, String> getEntry(String paramToFind,  Map<String, String> myMap) {
    return Map.entry(paramToFind, myMap.get(paramToFind));
}
```

Comment: Replace `Map.Entry` with `Map.Entry<String, String>`